# SQLalchemy select all with optional attributes

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

with SQLalchemy I query my database. I'm able to select all multiple rows / objects with something like this:

```
def selectAllObjects():
    objects = session.query(Object).all()
```

However, I want to build a function that checks if there any constraints given and if so incorporates these. So I was thinking along the following lines:

```
def selectAllObjects(attribute1="default",attribute2="default"):
    if attribute1 != "default" and attribute2 != default:
        objects = session.query(Object).filter_by(attribute1=attribute1,
                  attribute2=attribute2).all()
    elif attribute1 != "default":
        objects = session.query(Object).filter_by(attribute1=attribute1).all()
    ...etc, etc...
```

As you can see this gets really ugly when the amount of attributes increase. What is the pythonic way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

`Query` objects are chainable, from [docs](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html):

> Query is produced in terms of a given Session, using the query()
>   method:
>
> q = session.query(SomeMappedClass)

So you can write something like this:

```
def selectAllObjects(attribute1="default", attribute2="default"):
    query = session.query(Object)
    if attribute1 != "default" and attribute2 != "default":
        query = query.filter_by(
            attribute1=attribute1,
            attribute2=attribute2,
        )
    elif attribute1 != "default":
        query = query.filter_by(attribute1=attribute1)
    return query.all()
```

Comment: ah, so with 10 attributes, I can make a list of them and loop over the list (within the loop I check if attribute is set, and if so, narrow down the query)